# finding n-th combination in order statistics

Tags: combinatorics

`7` digit numbers are formed by using the digits `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`. We are allowed to use every digit only once, and the number shouldn't be divisible by `5`. If we sort all the combinations in ascending order, what will be the `2000`-th number in the list?

Also, is there a generalised way to approach n-th combination in ordered statistics problems like this?

Comment: To get started:  how many such strings begin with $1$?  How many begin with $2$?  Using this, what's the first digit of $a_{2000}$?

Comment: Also, clearly the numbers counted should **not** end in $5$ (else they'd be divisible by 5).  So there are six numbers that can end the seven-digit number.  For numbers beginning with 1, as lulu suggests, there are only five numbers that can end the the number.  Etc...

Comment: That exact question was already answered https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815720/all-the-7-digit-numbers-containing-each-of-the-digits-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-exactl?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All the 7-digit numbers containing each of the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 exactly once, and not divisible by 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815720/all-the-7-digit-numbers-containing-each-of-the-digits-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-exactl)